# What are the miracast supported video formats?

Tags: miracast

Developing and application for miracast.
That will transfer video data to tv's.
I would like to know what are the video formats support This feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By referring [this](http://www.wi-fi.org/knowledge-center/faq/what-formats-does-miracast-support) and [this](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2090127/screen-mirrors-how-chromecast-compares-to-miracast.html) Miracast devices can transmit data at 1080p resolution with 5.1-channel digital audio, which makes them ideal for sharing videos and music on your television.

> For video, Miracast supports the ITU-T H.264 video codec
>   (AKA Advanced Video Coding [AVC]) for high-definition video.
>   It supports the Constrained Baseline Profile (CBP) and the
>   Miracast-specific Constrained High Profile (CHP), at levels ranging
>   from 3.1 to 4.2. Supported display resolutions include common Consumer
>   Electronics Association (CEA) formats, Video Electronics Standards
>   Association (VESA) formats, and handheld formats.